# Webview javascript android

Tags: android-sdk

Мне нужно сделать графики с анимацией. Но под андроид подходящей библиотеки не нашел, а самому влом делать свои графики с блек-джеком и анимацией. Но есть библиотека для javascript http://www.zingchart.com/ там есть анимации. Вообщем можно ли генерить какой-то html+javascript у себя на девайсе и потом это действо запустить у себя на webView оффлайн?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да. У компонента WebView есть методы, позволяющие загрузить HTML файл, размещенный в папке **assets** вашего приложения:

```
  myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Соответственно, таким же образом можно загружать и JavaScript код, предварительно разрешив исполнять его WebView.

---

Также можно динамически генерировать и загружать контент в WebView:

```
String summary = "<html><body>MY DATA</body></html>";
myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

---

А вообще следовало бы, наверное, почитать хоть немного мануала, прежде чем мастерить приложения под Android - это же вам [не сайтики на PHP клёпать](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%A8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: щас попробую, если javascript будет работать и отпишу

Comment: Чтобы JS работал в вашем WebView, нужно это разрешить:

      myWebView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29

Comment: есть проблема. там мне надо использовать библиотеку js. если запихнуть папку с библиотекой тоже в assets то будет работать?

Comment: Будет, разумеется. Не запутайтесь только в указании верного пути к этой библиотеке.

Comment: я читаю стак, потому, что убедился в кривости андроида и наличии кучи подводных камней. много чего делал, но WebView ни разу не приходилось использовать, поэтому делать вывод что я школьник - это глупо.

Comment: Вы, разумеется, не школьник. Но ваше утверждение о "кривости Android" может заставить думать об обратном. Android слишком хорош и удобен с точки зрения разрабтки под него, чтобы суметь понять это с первых дней разработки.

Comment: как раз с первых дней разработки создается такое ложное впечатление. но потом это проходит. вы посмотрите исходники андроида. А потом всякие тонкости типо фокуса и правильного отображения клавиатуры. Особенно тонкости работы EditText в ListView, я могу еще кучу всего перечислить. Много есть подводных камней. С фрагментами там тоже нюансы.